# generate unique code using two variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a modal popup which populates Item Name and Item code from the Database.
I want to generate **unique ItemCode** which contains characters from ItemName and Item Number populated from Database.

Please help me to understand where to start with.
Thanks in advance....

Sample ITEM NAME AND ITEM NUMBER

ITEM NAME: **FG**

ITEM NUMBER:**45678**

Expected Item Code: **FG_456_1**

Comment: Atleast, post you sample Item Name and Item Number

Comment: Isn't item number unique? if name and number is same, how will you generate a unique code with them?

Comment: item number and Item Name both are Unique and Item code should be a combination of both ItemName and Item Number.

Comment: whats your logic behind that '_1' from where it is coming or is it random

Comment: At least post some code showing your effort?

Comment: Thanks @GauravChaudhary .. your example helped me  a lot in achieving the required result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like this but the logic is upto you like how you want to generate that last part '_1'

```js
function generateItemCode(itemName,itemNumber){
  var itemCode = ''
  itemCode = itemName +"_"+itemNumber.slice(0,3)+'_1'
  return itemCode
}


var code = generateItemCode('FG','45678')
console.log(code)
```